# Compile MySQL 5.5.15 from source using autorun.sh and cmake, unable to start MySQL after

Tags: mysql, debian-squeeze

I was trying to compile MySQL 5.5.15 from source in Debian 6 and was using the "old-fashioned" way of doing it: i.e., run autorun.sh in BUILD and then run ./configure with quite a few options, and when I tried to start the process, here is what I see:

```
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1595675
110816  9:36:06  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
110816  9:36:06  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
110816  9:36:07 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
110816  9:36:07 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
110816 09:36:07 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/myhost.pid ended
```

Here are the `./configure` options that I have used:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql --with-extra-charsets=all\
            --enable-thread-safe-client --enable-assembler \
            --with-charset=utf8 --enable-thread-safe-client \
            --with-extra-charsets=all
make && make install && make install scripts
```

And I have run install db as well:

```
/usr/local/mysql/scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql \
--basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/var
```

Added
the ownership is already changed, but the problem remained:

```
ls -la
total 20
drwx--S---  5 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 .
drwxr-sr-x 14 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 ..
drwx--S---  2 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 mysql
drwx--S---  2 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 performance_schema
drwx--S---  2 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 test
```

Could you please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the key

```
[ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
```

Make sure the data directory user is mysql

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /usr/local/mysql/var
```

Also check to make sure your data directory actually contains the mysql database and it's default tables that should have been created with the install script.

Comment: Mmm... I have already done this: ls -la
total 20
drwx--S---  5 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 .
drwxr-sr-x 14 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 ..
drwx--S---  2 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 mysql
drwx--S---  2 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 performance_schema
drwx--S---  2 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 16 09:25 test

Comment: what are the contents of the mysql folder? Also check to make sure your my.cnf is pointing to the correct data directory

Comment: ls -la | grep host
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql      0 Aug 16 09:25 host.MYD
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql   2048 Aug 16 09:25 host.MYI
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql   9510 Aug 16 09:25 host.frm

Comment: HOLY, the last point is the solution, I need to change my data dir to specifically point to /usr/local/mysql/var, thanks so much buddy, you saved me tonnes of time!

Answer (score 2):

Please use cmake instead of autotools.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-sourcebuild-excerpt/5.5/en/source-configuration-options.html

MySQL developers use the cmake for 5.5 branch, and "configure" is not supported anymore.